# Is it possible to mock an empty response body in Mockito

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, mockito

I am new to both writing tests and Mockito. I am trying to mock a call to an api which in one case is expected to return an empty response body. I can't seem to find a way to make this possible.

I am searching by name, through a database `employeeRepository`. I am passing in a name which doesn't exist, so an empty response body is returned and I am not sure how to represent that. This is what I have so far without knowing what to put in `thenReturn()`:

`when(employeeRepository.findEmployeeByName(NAME_1)).thenReturn();`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Mockito. It depends what you mean by empty response, It may be empty string, empty array or something else.
You could try with something like this:

```
when(employeeRepository.findEmployeeByName(NAME_1)).thenReturn("");
when(employeeRepository.findEmployeeByName(NAME_1)).thenReturn("{}");
```